# Selecting the fourth td in each row of a table and transforming data

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So ive got a function that should take the fourth column in every row of a specific table, manipulate the data with a function and return different data for the cell. It takes an integer of total minutes and returns a string to place in the cell. I've got the function working but only on the first one it finds in the first row. JQuery is still a bit new to me and I don't entirely understand how to work with the DOM via JS. Here's the function I have currently. I appreciate any help!

```
$('#customlists tbody tr td').eq(3).each(function() {
console.log($(this).html());
return $(this).html(convertTime($(this).html()));
});

function convertTime(minutes) {
console.log(minutes);
var days = Math.floor((minutes/60) / 24);
minutes -= days*60*24;
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
minutes -= hours*60;
return days+"D "+hours+"H "+minutes+"M ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.eq(3)` will select only the fourth item in the whole jQuery collection, resulting in only one element. Try using `nth-child` in the selector string instead:

```
$('#customlists tbody tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
```

```js
$('#customlists tbody tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
  $(this).text('FOUR');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="customlists">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>three</td>
      <td>four</td>
      <td>five</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>three</td>
      <td>four</td>
      <td>five</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well that makes sense! Thanks, that was exactly it. I guess i didn't understand exactly how eq() works. I appreciate your help and how super fast the answer came! Edit -- I'll accept it as the answer after the timer passes!

Comment: @LoganSwartz, Please consider upvoting and approving the answer.

Comment: @KetanYekale There is a time limit of 15 minutes before an asker can accept an answer.

Comment: Man you are too quick. :)